# How to get web scope feature GUID?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, jsom, feature

I want to get web scope feature GUID:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In JSOM API [`SP.Feature` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247054.aspx) exposes the following properties:

- `DefinitionId` - specifies the identifier for this feature
- `DisplayName`

The following example shows how to find a feature by `DisplayName` property and print its identifier:

**Example**

```
  var featureTitle = "TeamCollab";   //"Team Collaboration Lists"; 

  var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var features = ctx.get_web().get_features();
  ctx.load(features,'Include(DisplayName,DefinitionId)'); 
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(
     function(){

        var result = features.get_data().filter(function(f){
            //console.log(f.get_displayName()); 
            if(f.get_displayName() == featureTitle)
               return f;    
        });

        //print results
        for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
           console.log(result[i].get_definitionId().toString());
        }

     },
     function(sender,args){
        console.log(args.get_message()); 
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint online, you can now use PnP PowerShell to get the site/web feature details.

You have to use **Get-PnPFeature** command for fetching site feature details

**Documentation**: [Get-PnPFeature](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPFeature.html)

---

You can also get the GUID of SharePoint feature easily from browser itself:

[image]

**Source**: [Easiest way to get the GUID of SharePoint feature](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/03/easiest-way-to-get-the-guid-of-sharepoint-feature/)

Answer (score -1):

```
Get-SPFeature | ? {$_.DisplayName -eq "feature display name"}
Get-SPFeature | where { $_.DisplayName -like "*name*" }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work on SharePoint Online...

Comment: Have you tried installing and using the SharePoint Online Management Shell?

Comment: Sure, but these script are for SharePoint Server and not SharePoint Online. All SPO-scripts are listed here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161364.aspx

Comment: If you go below site enable-SPO Feature is also not mention in link which you have given. So I guess same way you can try.
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-enable-a-SharePoint-5bb614c7

Comment: Then that script should be mentioned and referenced in the answer to this question. Care to edit and update your answer?

Comment: -1 for the SP Server script.  If you update as suggested, I'll change it.